# Radio Button list selected items value in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am using following code to get the selected elements value in radio button list.

```
function SelectRadioButton()
{
   var radiobutton = document.getElementsByName('<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %>');
   alert(radiobutton.length);
for(var x = 0; x < radiobutton.length; x++)
            {
                if(radiobutton[x].checked)
                {
                    alert('selected is ' + radiobutton[x].id);
                }
             }
 }
```

Following is the HTML markup

```
  <table id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_idControl_RadioButtonList1" class="chk" onclick="javascript:SelectRadioButton(this, ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_idControl_RadioButtonList1)" border="0">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_idControl_RadioButtonList1_0" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$idControl$RadioButtonList1" value="1" checked="checked" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_idControl_RadioButtonList1_0">List</label></td><td><input id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_idControl_RadioButtonList1_1" type="radio" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$idControl$RadioButtonList1" value="2" /><label for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_idControl_RadioButtonList1_1">Assignment</label>
```

But I am getting length 0 in alert(radiobutton.length); statement.
Why is this happening. any thing that I am missing?

Comment: use jQuery, no one writes javascript like this anymore.

Comment: I think it should be  `if(radiobutton[x]:checked)`.

Comment: Thanx. But that is the later stage. I am not getting the length of elements.

Comment: can you show us radio button's rendered html markup?

Comment: I asked for rendered html (see in browser)

Comment: @Pramod: Can you post the rendered mark up?

Comment: @Pramod I have updated my answer below. have a look. it's working fine at my side

Comment: @Sachine thank you so much its returning me the length 2. But why use chk cssclass name. This class might be used by some other controls as well.

Comment: @Pramod you can use Id of element instead of class. I give it as just example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery to do this.

```
 alert($(".chk").find("input:checked").length); // chk is your css class name applied to Checkbox List element.
```

You can get specific element by using this

```
alert($(".chk").find("input:checked")[0]);
```

Comment: Is my looping Correct. because its not going inside that loop. it is satisfying the equation.

Answer (score 1):

`RadioButtonList1` will be converted to radio buttons with ids having `RadioButtonList1`, You can iterate through DOM and look for matched `ids` and put them in some array or directly perform what you want to them.

```
radiobutton = [];

for(i=0;i<document.forms[0].length;i++)
{
    e=document.forms[0].elements[i];
    if (e.id.indexOf("RadioButtonList1") != -1 )
    {
           radiobutton.push(e); 

    }       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it with javascript only, if you don't want to use `getElementById`

---

### Code | [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qusxt/)

```
function SelectRadioButton(){
    var radiolist = getElementsByClass("table", "chk")[0],
        radios = radiolist.getElementsByTagName("input");

    for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++){
        if(radios[i].checked){
            alert('Selected radiobutton is ' + radios[i].id);
        }
    }
 }

function getElementsByClass(tag, name){
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(tag);
    var ret = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
        if(elements[i].className.indexOf(name) !== -1){
            ret.push(elements[i]);
        }
    }

    return ret;
}
```